# Mocking a Java Interface in JRuby with RSpec-mock

Tags: rspec, interface, mocking, jruby, rspec-mocks

I'm  writing a simplistic wrapper for JDBC in JRuby. Essentially I want to have a wrapper class `DBW` that takes a connection string and an optional initialization block.

```
require 'java'

class DBW
    def initialize (connection_string, &optional_init_block)
        if optional_init_block
            yield
        end

        @connection_string = connection_string
    end
    def get_connection
        Java::java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(@connection_string)
    end
end
```

However in my test I want to use a test double as the `Driver` that registers with the `DriverManager`, so I've done the following in a RSpec test:

```
it "can produce a connection using the connection string" do 

    mock_conn = instance_double("Connection") # A dummy connection instance
    mock_driver = instance_double("Driver")
    allow(mock_driver).to receive(:acceptsURL).with(any_args) {
        # this doesn't get called when the wrapper calls getConnection on the DriverManager 
        true
    }
    # Expecting that connect would be called on the driver with the connecion string...
    allow(mock_driver).to receive(:connect).with(any_args).and_return(mock_conn)

    wrapper = DBW.new "jdbc:subprotocol:subname" do 
        # Initialize the DriverManager with the mock driver
        Java::java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(mock_driver)
    end

    # This should call in to DriverManager.getConnection
    conn = wrapper.get_connection
    expect(conn).to eq(mock_conn)

end
```

I get the following error running the test:

```
Failures:

  1) DBW can produce a connection using the connection string
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     Java::JavaSql::SQLException:
       No suitable driver found for jdbc:subprotocol:subname
     # java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(java/sql/DriverManager.java:689)
     # java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(java/sql/DriverManager.java:270)
     # java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:497)
     # RUBY.get_connection(/playground/dbw.rb:12)
     # RUBY.(root)(/playground/specs/dbw_spec.rb:39)
```

As noted in the test code the acceptsURL method is not getting called by the `DriverManager`. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

you're very likely hit `java.sql.DriverManager` internals that seem to mess with you. if you look at the .java source you'll see there's checks when obtaining connection on the caller's loader (before calling `connect` - `acceptsURL` is not relevant here). that might be something that blows up within JRuby, you can verify a `java.sql.Driver` generated instance is there but not returned when using the API :

```
java.sql.DriverManager.class_eval do
  field_reader :registeredDrivers
end

# ...

Java::java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(mock_driver)

puts java.sql.DriverManager.registeredDrivers.to_s # returns the mock_driver (last)
# [driver[className=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver@55974e79], driver[className=org.jruby.gen.InterfaceImpl1708146542@b02cbee]]
puts java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers.to_a.inspect  # does not return the mock_driver
# [#<Java::SunJdbcOdbc::JdbcOdbcDriver:0x55974e79>]
```

I recommend you refactor your code to be not tight to `DriverManager` too much ... or simply try out with a "real" (Java) mock driver compiled into a .jar added to the class-path